# Can I connect two external databases using Microsoft Access?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, odbc

First, I apologize if this has been asked or is a trivial question.

But, is it possible to connect to two external SQL databases through Microsoft Access?

By way of background one is our CRM and one is our email management system.  The two are completely distinct databases.  And, reside in different physical and virtual servers.

Our objective is to be able to gain insight into our email marketing efforts as it relates to client activities captured in our CRM.

We currently use an ODBC connection to read data from our CRM database.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaking, you want to use Access and just link to tables in 2 different databases?  Yeah, we've done that many times.  Why didn't you just try it before asking?

Comment: You can *connect to* two different data-sources (A and B) easily; but are you trying to *bridge* the data-sources (so A can access B *through* Access) or just *consume* both sources (A and B) *in* Access?

Answer (score 1):

Really, we need more information, but basically yes it is possible. All you need to do is link to the tables in the SQL databases, then run the query on the linked tables with a JOIN.
This page will tell you how to link to an SQL table: http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access-help/import-or-link-to-sql-server-data-HA010200494.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to do this in MS Access *(as already said in Makita's answer)*.

But you won't get the maximum performance this way, because there's a certain overhead caused by MS Access on your machine *(which is relatively slow compared to the DB servers and probably has a slower network connection than the DB servers)*, pulling data from two different DB servers over the network.

Since you tagged your question with [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server), there's another possible solution using a feature of SQL Server: [linked servers](http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/how-to-add-a-linked-server).

You can create a linked server in SQL Server A, that links to SQL Server B.
(see the above link for more information about how to do this)

Then, you can query tables on SQL Server B from SQL Server A *(and even join tables from both servers)* with the following syntax:

```
-- execute this on Server A

use DatabaseA

select *
from TableA a
inner join ServerB.DatabaseB.dbo.TableB b on a.ID = b.ID
```

*(this code assumes that `TableA` is a table in `DatabaseA`, which is on `ServerA`, and so on)*

This will be **way** faster than linking the tables in MS Access *(the more data you need to pull, the faster it will be)* because you're using the superior CPU power and network connection of the database servers.